# Flutter: http.post the object

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to send a http.post request with multiple variables.

```
var acc = {
    'acc_type': 'normal',
    'time': 'Jan 27',
  };

  var what = await http.post(
    'http://localhost:7200/api/activity/addactivity',
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(
      <String, dynamic>{
        'userId': 'aaa111',
        'location': 'hellooooo',
        'acc': acc
      },
    ),
  );
```

When I remove `acc: acc`, Flutter sends requests. However, I need to send `var acc` value to the server in order to post it. I tried to encode it to JSON the `http.post()` function. It seems not working. How can I send the object as part of the `post request`?

Comment: What is the error when you try to send the request with the acc parameter ?

Comment: So, I tried to print the error, but I don't see any error. I set `print()` methods in the beginning and the end of the request. Only the one in the beginning prints. Also, I set the `console.log()` on my server to console.log whenever I receive the request. It doesn't log anything. If I send the request without `acc: acc`, then it logs and request normally. I see all the console.logs and print methods being printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work.

```
import 'dart:convert';

//....

var what = await http.post(
 'http://localhost:7200/api/activity/addactivity',
  headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  },
  body: json.encode(
    <String, dynamic>{
      'userId': 'aaa111',
      'location': 'hellooooo',
      'acc': acc
    },
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var acc = {
'acc_type': 'normal',
'time': 'Jan 27',
};

var what = await http.post(
'http://localhost:7200/api/activity/addactivity',
headers: <String, String>{
  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
},
body:(
  <String, dynamic>{
    'userId': 'aaa111',
    'location': 'hellooooo',
    'acc': acc.toString(),
  },
),
);
```